# Sending data between mobile app and PHP application

Tags: php, android

I have a PHP application and Android application, and need to authorize users from mobile application and allow them to add/edit data.

How can I maintain the session for the mobile user? What will the most feasible way to do this in a secure manner?

Comment: PHP sessions. End of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mobile device have a device token smiler format to "vbnji865trfvbhu654erfgy4efgy54refghyu754ref" this unique string can be used for authorization.

- Mobile App will send a request to your application including the token
- You verify the token and process the request then you send the result to mobile app
- The mobile app will present the result to user.

http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token

most developer choose json format to communicate with mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use **Java** + [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html).

Suppose you want to use POST method. Send your data as Json String.

**PHP side**

```
 $data = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $dataJ = json_decode($data, TRUE);

 ...
```